# I want to merge files starts with same name

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, merge

I have multiple files, more than 100 like below and I need to merge same name files in to 1 file by concatenating them together.

```
AB_HCE_USERS_20221228_001.txt
AB_HCE_USERS_20221228_002.txt
AB_HCE_TASKS_20221228_001.txt
AB_HCE_TASKS_20221228_002.txt
AB_HCE_TASKS_20221228_003.txt
AB_HCE_ASSESSMENTS_20221228_001.txt
AB_HCE_ASSESSMENTS_20221228_002.txt
AB_HCE_CONTACT_20221228_003.txt
AB_HCE_CONTACT_20221228_004.txt
AB_HCE_CONSUMERS_20221228_001.txt
AB_HCE_VERIFICATION_20221228_001.txt
AB_HCE_VERIFICATION_20221228_002.txt
AB_HCE_CONSUMER_RELATIONSHIP_20221228_001.txt
AB_HCE_CONSUMER_RELATIONSHIP_20221228_002.txt
...
```

Desired output:

```
AB_HCE_USERS_20221228.txt
AB_HCE_TASKS_20221228.txt
AB_HCE_ASSESSMENTS_20221228.txt
AB_HCE_CONTACT_20221228.txt
AB_HCE_CONSUMERS_20221228.txt
AB_HCE_VERIFICATION_20221228.txt
AB_HCE_CONSUMER_RELATIONSHIP_20221228.txt
..
```

Comment: The filenames are specified in a file? or your files actually are part of the filesystem and you want to remove them from it?

Comment: Also, do all your filenames contain exactly two underscore `_`?

Comment: What does "merging" mean to you? Delete all but one? Concatenate the contents? In which order? Or are the contents somehow structured data where "merging" is a well-defined behavior? This needs **much** more information and a display of what you've tried so far, even and especially if manual.

Comment: It's also highly unlikely that whatever it is, it hasn't been asked before, so please refer to the things you've already researched.

Comment: All files are in a file system starts with AB_HCE_*. And few files also contains more 4 underscore _ . EX. AB_HCE_CONSUMER_RELATIONSHIP_20221228_001.txt

Comment: merge means concatenate the content into 1 file

Comment: @sv as Marcus said, does the order matter? E.g. These two files `AB_HCE_USERS_20221228_001.txt` `AB_HCE_USERS_20221228_002.txt` should concatenate first `AB_HCE_USERS_20221228_001.txt` and then `AB_HCE_USERS_20221228_002.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in AB*.txt; do
    awk -F'_[0-9]+.txt$' '{
        system("cat "$0" >> ("$1".txt"));
        close($1".txt")
    }' <<< "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `gawk`:

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE {out = FILENAME; sub(/_[^_]*$/, ".txt", out)}
  {print > out}' ./*_[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]].txt
```

Note that that will add line delimiters for lines that don't have one. Replace `print` with `printf "%s", $0 RT` to avoid it. If source files for a given file are all empty, no corresponding output file is created/truncated. You could add a `printf "" > out` to the `BEGINFILE` statement to address that.

With `zsh`, without the limitations above and not limited to 000...999 numbers (using the `n` glob qualifier to make sure file names are sorted numerically):

```
typeset -A map=()
for f (*_<->.txt(NDn.)) map[${f%_*}]+=$f$'\0'
for out files (${(kv)map}) cat -- ${(0)files} > $out.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple pattern for bash:

```bash
for i in AB_*; do
    cat $i >> ${i%_*}.txt
done
```

In order to avoid possible collisions, it is better to create a separate directory for new files: `cat $i >> my_dir/${i%_*}.txt`. It is also possible to change the mask to: `for i in AB_*_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt`

Comment: This works for the example data, but may need modification if it should merge files which have the same base name but multiple different dates before the final underscore.

Comment: @tripleee, Added explanations to the pattern